# Two new columns based on return has two values in dataframe apply

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame:

```
    Num
     1
     2
     3
```

```
def foo(x):
    return x**2, x**3
```

When I did `df['sq','cube'] = df['num'].apply(foo)`
It is making a single column like below:

```
    num    (sq,cub)
     1       (1,1)
     2       (4,8)
     3       (9,27)
```

I want these column separate with their values

```
     num sq cub 
     1   1   1
     2   4   8
     3   9   27
```

How can I achieve this...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
obj = df['num'].apply(foo) 
df['sq'] = obj.str[0]
df['cube'] = obj.str[1]
```

Comment: alternatively, just do - `df['sq'] = df['num']**2` & `df['sq'] = df['num']**2` & `df['cube'] = df['num']**3`. No need for apply in this case.

Comment: @sharathnatraj Thanks for response. My above example is just a simulation to my actual problem. So the accepted answer is the solution to that problem.